# Caliburn.Micro Action Parameters for $source

Tags: caliburn.micro

When writing methods for Action Parameters in Caliburn.Micro:

If ActionExecutionContext is the class you use to pass $executionContext, and if KeyEventArgs is the claas you use to pass $eventArgs, then what class do you use to pass $source?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the class of the $source, you could use directly it, either you could use object and test casting.. See a sample with DependencyObject

```
<Button  Content="SelectAll"  cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action SelectAll($source)]" />
```

---

```
    public void SelectAll(object sender)
    {
        if (sender is DependencyObject)
           //something to do

        //or 
        var Grid = (DependencyObject)sender);

    }
```

if you know the class sended:

```
public void SelectAll(DependencyObject sender)
{


}
```